# In SQL Server, how can I perform a series of queries without creating intermediary tables with different names or renaming/dropping?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine I want to apply sequentially two different queries to a table:

```
select * 
  into #temp_table1
  from original_table
  ...
select *
  into #temp_table2
  from #temp_table1
  ...
```

I don't really need the intermediary temp_table1, but it's an input to create temp_table2. Also assume I can't merge both queries and don't want to create nested queries (since the sequence can be infinitely long).

I'd rather be able to implicitly overwrite it and write something like:

```
select * 
  into #temp_table
  from original_table
  ...
select *
  into #temp_table
  from #temp_table
  ...
```

This way, I wouldn't need to explicitly create the intermediary step tables. It makes easier to write and modify a script. I'm doing this solely for the purpose of analysis, I won't be creating indexes or constraints for these temporary tables.

I could do it with sp_rename and drop, but it's cumbersome to do it after every query. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: You wont need many staging tables, depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you align data types correctly you can minimize the use of any staging tables.

Comment: What is the problem if you write sequential queries? With no use of intermediate tables. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos I use as input the result of the previous query

Comment: @WillianRazente I do not see any consistency problem with sequential execution.. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: You can always use nested selects or CTE's for that, if you don't want to persist the results. You can also save the results in temporary tables (`select * into #temp_table1 from original table`) - notice the pound # symbol, which will be discarded when the session ends (you close the SSMS tab).

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos there's no consistency problem, I just don't want to pollute my db with a million temp tables, or pollute my script with a million renames/drops.

Comment: Are you familiar with the "With" statement and [Common table Expressions?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: @xQbert, not yet! Reading into it

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu persisting the results or not is not my problem, I've edited the question to make it clearer, thank you! I'm reading about CTE though

Comment: Alternatively, one could reuse the tablename by adding a column to indicate the "set of data" or the iteration #.  So add a column int with value 1-x and you can just select the max value from the column to get the most recent set entered...add one each time you insert a new dataset.  something like... `Insert into #temp values (Select Col1,col2....DataSet+1 from #temp where DataSet = (Select max(dataset) from #temp))`

Comment: @WillianRazente Sorry that I am repeating myself, but I am trying to understand the question. Let's say u have 20 Select/Update/Insert/Update command to a table. What is the problem executing all of them without any intermediate table or rename?

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos the intermediary tables may have different structures among themselves, so I can't work with a single table and just update/insert/delete. That's why I need to store the results step by step. Also, even if I could just update/insert/delete, it would take longer to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your latest question edit, I can see the CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) as being the last solution. Below is a solution with nested CTE's.

```
;with temp_table1 as (
    select *
    from original_table
    ...)
, temp_table2 as (
    select *
    from temp_table1
    ...)
, temp_table3 as (
    select *
    from temp_table2
    ... )
, master_CTE as (
    select *
    from temp_table3
    ...)
select *
from master_CTE
```

This will allow you to have a "recursive" and "infinite" pattern of writing your query.

The only thing you want to make sure is that the last part of your query is a `SELECT` from your last "CTE", I've called mine "master_CTE" for the lack of a better idea.

If you do however want to persist your final results it's as easy as adding the `INTO` clause, like so:

```
, master_CTE as (
        select *
        from temp_table3
        ...)
select *
into persisted_master_CTE
from master_CTE;
```

***Based on your comment:***

You don't really want to modify "all indices" because you probably don't care about the naming sequence, only the execution sequence. You add the new "processing" intermediary CTE and then adjust the references.

It's just like adding an element to a [single linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) (if you try to view this differently).

So, you can name them like so:

```
;with temp_table1 as (
    select *
    from original_table
    ...)
, temp_table2 as (
    select *
    from temp_table1
    ...)
, intermediary_step (      -- <-- since you needed to do some additional analysis here
     select *
     from temp_table2
     ... )
, temp_table3 as (
    select *
    from intermediary_step -- <-- the intermediary step
    ... )
, master_CTE as (
    select *
    from temp_table3
    ...)
select *
from master_CTE
```

Comment: Imagine though that I had 20 steps and I wanted to include a new query between steps 10 and 11. How do I avoid needing to modify all the subsequent table indices?

Comment: I think that's as good as it gets, but still doesn't solve code maintainability though. For example, in SAS's proc sql I can do exactly what I described in the question using CTAS, with a single explicit temporary table. SAS automatically handles the "overwrite".